# Test invalid function arguments with TypeScript and JestJS

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I've beend creating a node application with typescript and I'm using jest to write unit tests.

My issue: I can't really write unit tests simulating invalid function argument types, because typescript won't compile. I mean it's nice that typescript realises that I try to put wrong data in those functions, but the way I understood ts so far is, it only works during compile time. There won't be any checks of argument types during runtime.

So I still have to test the correct behaviour of my IO depending functions with jest, right?

I thought I'll just write a xyz.spec.**js** that and leave all the interfaces and types behind for that specific test. But then I receive an error from jest regarding the import of modules. I guess because it's not a ts file.

Do I have to change my jest or ts setup to make it work?

Here is a screenshot of the test and the error:

[image]

here my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "state",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "files": [
    "build"
  ],
  "main": "build/index",
  "types": "build/index",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf build && rimraf coverage",
    "format": "prettier --write \"{src,__tests__}/**/*.ts\" --single-quote --trailing-comma es5",
    "lint": "tslint --force --format verbose \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "start": "node ./build/index.js",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean && npm run format && npm run lint && echo Using TypeScript && tsc --version",
    "build": "tsc --pretty",
    "build:watch": "nodemon --legacy-watch src/index.ts",
    "test": "jest --no-cache",
    "test:watch": "jest --no-cache --watch",
    "coverage": "jest --no-cache --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^5.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.13",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.14.7",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.2",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

and here my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "target": "es2015",
    "outDir": "./<%= buildpath %>",
    "removeComments": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

Best regards
fea

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What it solved for me in the end was to allow js for typescript. So my new tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "target": "es2015",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "removeComments": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use `as any` in the argument of your test. That way you can add the "wrong" type and test your code with it. Assuming you want to test the `someFunction()` function which expects some sort of Prop object, for instance

```
interface Prop {
    id: number;
    type: string;
}

function someFunction(props: Prop): void {
    // ... do some stuff
}
```

Then your test could look something like this:

```js
it('should not accept the wrong argument type', () => {
    const props = { id: 123 };
    const testSomeFunction = () => {
        someFunction(props as any);
    };
    expect(testSomeFunction).toThrow();
});
```

You could also have a look at Type Guards, to do runtime type checks:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

```js
function isValidProp(prop: Prop): prop is Prop {
    const keys = ['id', 'type'];
    return Object.keys(prop).every(key => keys.includes(key));
}

function someFunction(props: Prop): void {
    if(!isValidProp(prop)){
        throw new Error('invalid prop!');
    }
    // ... do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what [@ts-expect-error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments) is for. It tells typescript to suppress the following error so that you can write tests that otherwise would not compile. Unlike @ts-ignore, it also generates an error if the following statement does not actually produce an error. Here is an example:

```
class NotANumberError extends Error {
  constructor(msg: string) {
    super(msg);
    this.name = 'NotANumberError';
  }
}

function acceptsNumber(x: number): void {
  if (typeof x !== 'number') {
    throw new NotANumberError(`expected number, received ${x}`);
  }
}

describe('acceptsNumber', () => {
  it('throws NotANumberError when called with string', () => {
    // @ts-expect-error test passing invalid string argument
    expect(() => acceptsNumber('hello')).toThrow(NotANumberError);
  });
});
```

The `acceptsNumber('hello')` would normally not compile, but that error gets suppressed by the `@ts-expect-error` comment above it, allowing us to run and test the code even when types mismatch.